# C++/Cli Stack Semantics and Tracking-Reference Operator

Tags: c++-cli

What's the difference between these two definitions:

```cxx
using namespace System;

String^ ToStringA(char* str)
{
    return gcnew String(str);
}

String^ ToStringB(char* str)
{
    return %String(str);
}
```

My guess is that in the latter a `System::String` is created with "stack semantics" to return a reference to that object with the `%`-operator, so it does the exact same thing as the former. Is that true? Any subtleties?

The `gcnew`-way is probably clearer here, hence preferred, but what about the following:

```cxx
String^ ToString2A(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    return gcnew String(str1) + gcnew String(str2);
}

String^ ToString2B(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    return %String(str1) + %String(str2);
}
```

where any other processing could be done instead of just concatenation. Any reason not to use the `%`?

Bonus question: why does this even work while [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx) say there is no stack-semantics for `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack semantics is a pure compiler feature, it completely disappears in the generated MSIL.  The compiler auto-generates the required `gcnew` to create the String object.  And would normally auto-generate the Dispose() call, but does not in this case since the String type does not implement IDisposable.

You only needed the `%` operator to keep the compiler happy, it does not actually produce any code.  The auto-generated String object is already a reference type.

So the two snippets are completely identical and generate the exact same MSIL.  Something you can verify by looking at it with a decompiler like ildasm.

Favor the most readable and logical version of it.  Which surely is the first one, using stack semantics on a non-disposable type makes no sense and only confuses the stuffing out of anybody that reads the code.  But it is up to you.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies a bit what stack semantics actually means. Still not clear in which way `String` would be among the reference types "not available for use with stack semantics"...

Comment: Stack semantics is a trick to rescue the holy RAII pattern in native C++.  Deterministic destruction, not something that is possible when you have a garbage collector.  Nor necessary, the garbage collector does not suck.  Except in the specific case of a class implementing the IDisposable interface.  Necessary when it requires a system resource *other* than memory.  Like a file, FileStream is disposable, you want to close the file when you're done with it, not wait until the GC gets around to it.  String only uses memory is therefore not disposable, it doesn't need any help.